# Error installing ODAC 12c with ODT for Visual Studio due to illegal character in node

Tags: windows-7, installation, odac

I'm getting this error while installing ODAC with ODT in my Windows 7 x86 dev box:

[image: Error]

It reads: *One or more node names 'pc_xxxx' contain one or more of the following invalid characters "_"*

My company network domain and my machine name both have an underscore in their names and that's obviously something I can't control nor ask for modifications.

I tried to install it with the -silent flag and tried to generate a response file with the -record -destinationFile c:\resp.rsp command to no avail because the response file is not generated (cmd window just closes, without showing an error).

Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: You can check [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97408/error-prvg-11322-while-atempting-to-install-odac-12c-release-3) provided by Robert L